# With Puppeteer How To Upload Random Files From A Directory and Delete It?

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, puppeteer, fs

I want to write a puppeteer script with node js to upload a random file from a directory to the server and delete it.

Here is the HTML code in the site:

```
<form action="/server.php">
  <input type="file" id="myFile" name="filename">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

So now I need to upload an image file from a directory (but I don't know the image name) and after that, I need to delete that file from the directory.

Here is my current puppeteer code:

```
//UPLOAD A PICTURE
const fileName = 'dont-know-the-name.png';
const picInput = await page.$('#myFile');
await picInput.uploadFile(fileName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, what takes care of uploading a file is [Puppeteer's `ElementHandle.uploadFile()` method.](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleuploadfilefilepaths). You would want to use Node's [`fs.readDir()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreaddirpath-options-callback) to get an array of the file in the dir, take a random element and then use [`fs.unlink()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsunlinkpath-callback) to delete it.

Here's an implementation:

```js
const dir = "YOUR/DIR/PATH";
const rnd = (arr) => arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
const rndFile = () => `${dir}/${rnd(fs.readdirSync(dir))}`;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto("YOUR/UPLOAD/URL")
    
  const file = rndFile();
  const elementHandle = await page.$("input[type=file]");
  await elementHandle.uploadFile(file);
  await page.click("input[type=submit]")
  
  fs.unlinkSync(file)
})();
```